# Should I avoid using "Switch"?

Tags: loops, switch-statement

In this case I'm working on a 2D game. In this game, I need few missile types fall from sky as a bomberman. Each missile type, on collision with my character, hurts a determined amount of damage depending on the missile type.

What should I do?

- Option 1: create a single class Missile which contains a variable with its own missile type, and in the checking loop for collision I use Switch to decide the damage.
- Option 2: create few classes, then make same number of missile collision check loops avoiding using switch, knowing in each loop the damage.
- Option 3: create a single check loop, with all missiles, and use heritance to make distintions between missiles
- Option 4: dont save missile type, instead, initialize the missiles with their damage and other many variables that will be the same for the same missile type  (waste of memory)

And if option 3 doesnt exist, option 1 or 2?

Thanks

Comment: Why not?  It's part of the language.  Just be careful, and don't forget the breaks.

Comment: If there are only a few values that vary between the types, and the behavior is otherwise the same, I'd go with option 4 if it makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, option 3 is quite feasible.

You have a missile class that has the damage variable.
All other types of missiles extend this class. So you can add other fields of info as needed.

so when you loop through all the missile classes. you can cast them to (missile) and then assess that variable.

Comment: Remember to use instanceof when subclass instances.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how different each missile type is as well as what you plan for the future.  If all the types are there, you don't plan to add more types, and the only thing different between types is their damage amount, I would go with the switch.  However, to make it easier for expansion as well as modeling different behavior for each missile type that goes beyond just damage amounts, I would create a base class and inherit a new class for each type allowing you to overload methods like `getDamage()` or `updateMovement()` for each missile type.

Answer (score 0):

Give each `Missle` subclass a method that calculates the damage, taking whatever arguments it needs.  Give each target a `applyDamage` (or just `damage`) method that applies the specified amount of damage to the target.

Prefer polymorphism to switches.

Prefer breaking methods down into the smallesat coherent set of tasks.